# How to install pgdb on MacOS Mavericks?

Tags: python-2.7, osx-mavericks, pycharm, pgdb

I updated my system to Mavericks and I have a python code using pgdb. How can I install pgdb on my new mac?

I tried

```
sudo pip install git+git://github.com/cancerhermit/pgdb.py.git
```

And

```
sudo pip install pgdb
```

And

```
brew install pgdb
```

And I have even tried to install it from PyCharm directly (my first try).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Mac OSX ( E-Caption- 10.11.2  ).

```
pip install PyGreSQL
```

Worked for me.

```
>     Collecting PyGreSQL   Downloading PyGreSQL-4.1.1.tgz (100kB)
>     100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 2.9MB/s
> 
> Building wheels for collected packages: PyGreSQL   
>   Running setup.py
>    bdist_wheel for PyGreSQL   Stored in directory:
>    <blah>441bbb4b4f3da670bbd24afa6a8a887cb1b16359dc4c26f445 Successfully
>    built PyGreSQL Installing collected packages: PyGreSQL Successfully
>    installed PyGreSQL-4.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded the [source code on PyGreSQL website](http://pygresql.org/files/PyGreSQL.tgz). Then I typed the following commands:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Based on what is recommended on [PyGreSQL install page](http://www.pygresql.org/install.html).

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. Somehow installing using pip got me pgdb, but not the 'connect' module within it, which is weird. But installing this way worked perfect.