# How to install pgdb on MacOS Yosemite?

Tags: python-2.7, osx-yosemite, postgresql-9.3, pgdb

On Mavericks, I downloaded the [source code](http://pygresql.org/files/PyGreSQL.tgz) and and [built and installed it with Distutils](http://www.pygresql.org/install.html) as I explained on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882125/how-to-install-pgdb-on-macos-mavericks).

I try to reproduce it on Yosemite and I have the following error message:

> Exception: pg_config tool is not available.

The command in 'setup.py' that generates the problem is supposed to "Retrieve information about installed version of PostgreSQL."

> f = os.popen('pg_config --%s' % s

I used the [graphic installer to install PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/) on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

The graphic installer did not work. By using Homebrew to install PostgreSQL, everything worked fine.

> brew install postgresql